# Add editText to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to add editText and textView to a fragment. The code to generate the editText and TExtView is correct because I've used it before, but in this case nothing appears. Any ideas?

Fragment code:

```
public class MarcadoresFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_marcadores, container, false);
    return myFragmentView;
}
```

}

Add the editText:

```
public void createEditText(int size){
    Log.d("det", String.valueOf(size));

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_marcadores, null);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.marcadoresFrag); // this is whatever view you want to add them to

    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;

    if(layout!=null)
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

            textView = new TextView(dialogView.getContext());
            textView.setText("Descrição do marcador " + String.valueOf(i + 1));

            textView.layout(0, 5, 0, 5);

            // add to the view
            layout.addView(textView);

            editText = new EditText(dialogView.getContext());

            editText.setId(i);
            editText.setHint("Ex: Bebedouro ndsfhjdsjvdsbjvjhvjdfjbvfjfvjklbjklfv" + i + 1);

            Log.d("det", "jsdgbiusdbgksjd");

            allEds.add(editText);

            // add to the view
            layout.addView(editText);
        }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling this createEditText(int size) function? can you post the entire fragment code?

Comment: the createEditText(int size) is called in an Activity. My fragment code is only that.

Comment: so you are trying to add EditText and TextiView from Activity to Fragment? why you are doing so? why don't you create the EditText and TextView in the Fragment itself

Comment: you used this code before for an activity or fragment?

Comment: I don't create in the fragment itself because i need the size. I used the code before for an activity